# Arrays - how to exclude columns from databodyrange (or retain formulas)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I've been recently experimenting with arrays and tables and found out when I've transferred the entire array back to the table via this code:

```
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim SPArr As Variant
Dim lCount As Long

vArr =ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("catalogue").ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Value2

For lCount = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
    Select Case vArr(lCount, 1)
    Case "G-6R-15L2" 'These are model names
        vArr(lCount, 4) = 4.8
    Case "G-6SPF-ZB2"
        vArr(lCount, 4) = 4.5
    Case "U6-6S-15L2"
        vArr(lCount, 4) = 6
    Case "U-6S-30H2"
        vArr(lCount, 4) = 9
    Case "G-6SP-12L2"
        vArr(lCount, 4) = 4.5
    End Select
Next lCount
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("catalogue").ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Value2 = vArr
```

The active formulas I had on column 3 are gone :( .I'll illustrate what it looks like before here:

[image]

Does any bright souls know how to exclude certain columns when referencing a table's databodyrange for an array? Like:

```
vArr(1) =ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("catalogue").ListObjects(1).listcolumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value2
vArr(2)=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("catalogue").ListObjects(1).listcolumns(2).DataBodyRange.Value2
```

Just that the above does not work in syntax :(, or some other suggested best practices ie doing the formulation for the two columns in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to replace "**.Value2**" with "**.Formula**"

Similar to this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub testFormulas()
    Dim v As Variant

    With Sheet1.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
        v = .Formula
        .Clear
        .Formula = v
    End With
End Sub
```

The array will now contain the formulas, and you're only updating column 4 so your code should work, but make sure you don't replace the formulas with values in your array

Comment: works like a charm! I've tried it and I'd assume that .formula is the same as .value but with formulas as well? A second question is that would I be able to change formulas within the array using .formula?

Comment: oh dear I just realized that the .formula has to be constant throughout the column, now this would be interesting

Comment: I wonder if it would be way easier if I could just exclude all the columns from my array save columns 1 & 2

Comment: 1. ".formula is the same as .value but with formulas as well" - that's correct 2. "would I be able to change formulas within the array using .formula?" - no, but you can change formulas in arrays just like changing the values: vArr(lCount, 4) = "=Sum(A1 + B1)" 3 Probably easier if you use several arrays and exclude all the formula columns